Adding post install scripts to my electron app using electron-forge
I've created an electron app and I'm packaging it using electron forge for both Mac and windows. I usually create .dmg files for mac but on windows the application launches as soon as the installation is done which is not the case with the .dmg files on mac.
So I started creating .pkg files and I also created a shell script and added it to my packager config inside forge.config.js  as follows
{
name: '@electron-forge/maker-pkg',
config: {
identity: "",
scripts: "./build/Scripts"
},
platform: ['darwin']
}
Inside my scripts folder I have my shell script as postinstall.sh
The script works as expected when I run the file through terminal. But the script is not running after installation on the user's devices as expected of it.
Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong? Please help.
I updated forge.config.js as mentioned on the electron-forge documentation but the scripts are still not running.
